# Pass Java ArrayList to javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I know this issue have been already discussed [Get Request Attributes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933866/get-request-attributes-in-javascript), but it still doesn't work for me. So, it isn't duplicate.

I renew my page asynchronously via javascript: send request (XMLHttpRequest object) and set XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = handleResponse().

**Question**: It is possible to handle java ArrayList request attribute (that come from server with response) in my handleResponse() function?

- All iteraction preceed in the same way as in the link above

Comment: JavaScript can't access your request attributes directly. But you can use the request attribute in your JSP/Servlet to render it as a javascript variable, so it's available when the script is executing. If you're doing an async request, it's probably better to convert and pass it as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and actually quite simple. Just use an encoding format, like JSON. There are plenty of Java JSON libraries out there. Have a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as well. Then from inside JavaScript, you can convert JSON to actual JavaScript objects and do whatever you want with them.