# Servlet not sending parameter to .jsp file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

So, I have this Servlet that should send a parameter to a .jsp file:

```
request.setAttribute("parameter1", new BigDecimal(50));
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB/pages/page1.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

However, when I try to alert this parameter with some javascript code inside the jsp, I get an empty message. Also, if I print the attribute to the console with Java using JSP Expression, I'm getting null.. So, I think I'm not correctly sending the parameter in this servlet, can someone help me here?

Comment: Have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933866/get-request-attributes-in-javascript

Comment: @BrianKates , no work.. However, I've just spotted what I think to be the error, I'm going to update the post.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can accomplish this.

Using a JSP *expression* you would use `<%= %>` as (notice no `;` at the end)

```
data : [<%= parameter1 %>, Y, Z]
```

The second and **preferred** way is to use JSP EL syntax and reference the `request` attribute directly using `${ }` as

```
data : [${parameter1}, Y, Z]
```

The first option requires you to pull the attribute out of its scope first. The second doesn't.

```
BigDecimal parameter1 = (BigDecimal) request.getAttribute("parameter1");
```

Comment: Allright, I'm able to alert the parameter with that ${parameter1}, however, and because of that, I've just noticed that the parameter is null (I'm alerting an empty message).. So, in other words, maybe the error is the way I'm passing the parameter in the servlet, because setAttribute is not doing the job.. Could it be?

Comment: question solved, I'm going to post the answer. Thanks for answering anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

I can't really see the difference, but just changing from:

```
request.setAttribute("parameter1", new BigDecimal(50));
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB/pages/page1.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

to:

```
request.setAttribute("parameter1", new BigDecimal(50));
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB/pages/page1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

allowed the `alert(${parameter1});` to display the actual value that I passed, however, I still got null when reading the parameter with java. Also, some javascript code I had to display a chart stopped working.

So, I've tried to pass the parameters by session:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("parameter1", new BigDecimal(50));
request.sendRedirect("/WEB/pages/page1.jsp");
```

This worked fine, now I can get my parameters both with javascript and java in the .jsp file.

It seems that redirecting to a new request using `sendRedirect` doesn't crash the javascript code in the .jsp file, however, I don't really know why this approach is working face the others, so I apologize for this poor answer, I've never really worked much with servlets and Jsp's but I really appreciate a more conclusive answer than mine, so I get to learn more too.